# Is there a way to audit CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations in oracle apex by users session

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to audit CRUD (mostly delete, update) operations on all my tables (740 tables) from my oracle apex application, and show which user (preferably user session id from apex) has committed changes in tables.

APEX_WORKSPACE_ACTIVITY_LOG only shows reports on clicks and even developers, but not changes in tables data.
I have tried oracle audit on my schema, but its audits are not useful for me because it doesn't show which user and which session has update or delete a record.
I can use triggers but it's not best option considering I have more than 740 tables in application.
And it seems like APEX_ACTIVITY_LOG is not working for me although I have activate it from inside oracle APEX, and I'm not sure if this is the solution. I would appreciate your help, solutions and recommendations.

Comment: 'APEX_ACTIVITY_LOG` only records page views, not DML operations. What version of Oracle Database are you using, and is the Unified Audit Trail enabled? Using Unified Auditing or Fine Grained Auditing in combination with the `SYS_CONTEXT` function should give you what you're looking for without adding the overhead of trigger management or otherwise reinventing the auditing wheel.

Comment: I finally solved the problem using Unified Auditing and auditing all tables instead of schema. Now It shows me the session from Oracle APEX inside the CLIENT_ID column in audit logs. I don't know if this is the best solution but at least it is working accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

APEX doesn't have this kind of functionality out of the box but you can write your own or check what the community has done. Best place to start is [this blog](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2020/08/04/level-up-your-audit-trigger-game/).